# How to display 'tree' data in the view in Cake PHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I am doing the [tree tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html) and would like to display the data in a view and wrap it in html etc. I am new to Cake PHP and this has been a bit of a pain. Below is an example of what I've tried. In short, I figure I could assign the output to a variable using set. I am doing everything wrong.

**Controller**

```
<?php

class CategoriesController extends AppController {

    public function index() {

      $this->set('output', $this->Category->generateTreeList(null, null, null, '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'));
    }
}

?>
```

**View**

```
   <?php foreach ($output as $data): ?>

        <div><?php echo $data['Category']['name']; ?></div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php unset($data); ?>
```

Comment: Tip: [cakephp-and-tree-structures/](http://www.dereuromark.de/2013/02/17/cakephp-and-tree-structures/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unlike other find methonds, `generateTreeList` doesen't return a named array but a plain array with numeric indexes

try `print_r($output)` and you'll see how the array is formatted and how you can use it in your view

to show your data, in your foreach cicle you just have to do this

```
echo $data;
```

Comment: echo $data['name']; doesn't work. I get:    Illegal string offset 'name' [APP/View/Categories/index.ctp, line 3]                                             I have 'name' as a field in the table.

Comment: sorry, just `echo $data`